# How to detect css blur support with Modernizr?

Tags: modernizr

How can I detect if browser supports css blur?

Can I use any of these default classes Modernizr puts to html tag?

borderimage borderradius boxshadow textshadow opacity cssanimations csscolumns cssgradients no-cssreflections csstransforms csstransforms3d csstransitions

I'd need to disable all blurs (or enable) css blurs to only supported browsers in css. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you go to: https://modernizr.com/download?setclasses, and then select the CSS Filters you will see the following example:

```
CSS

.no-cssfilters .box { color: red; }
.cssfilters .box { color: green; }

JS

if (Modernizr.cssfilters) {
  // supported
} else {
  // not-supported
}
```

I believe that this is what you need.